# Loop with a random

Tags: infinite-loop

I made a little picker, it just says yes or not, but idk why it stucks in a loop i the `While`
Here is it:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim kk As Integer
    kk = CInt(Int(Rnd() * 100) + 1)

    While (kk <> 0 Or kk <> 1)
        kk = kk / 2
    End While

    lblSiNo.Text = kk.ToString

End Sub
```

If it's `1`, is a Yes, if it's `0`, is No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
While (kk <> 0 Or kk <> 1)
```

Every integer is different from 0 or 1, it can't be both equals to 1 and 0. Your predicate is always true.

Comment: So the `kk = kk/2` is doing nothing there?

Comment: Your loop means "while kk is not 0 and 1 at the same time, divide kk by 2". This is a logical impossibility.

Comment: Theres an Or, so how can i put an OR there?

Comment: I have no idea what language you used, because you didn't tell us in your post, but usually <> means different. Try to replace it with the symbol for logical equality of this specific language if you want to stop your loop when kk equals 0 or 1 (also, kk is an integer and kk/2 may not be equal to a integer. I assume you are aware of this and know the consequence).

Comment: Is Visual Basic

Comment: Documentation about comparaison operators https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators

Your problem is you want to stop when the value is 0 or 1, but wrote you want it to stop when it is different from 0 or different from 1, which is always true (if it's equals to 0, it is not equals to 1, and vice et versa).

Comment: Do it while kk is not 0 or 1
If it reach 1, it end the loop
That's what i understand or im so lost in it?

Comment: Loop ends when the condition in the while is false, not when it is true. Your loop means :  "while kk is different from 0 or kk is different from 1, do this"
As you wrote it, you would need kk different from 0 and kk different from 1 to be both false (so both kk = 0 and kk = 1 at the same time) to end your loop.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

Comment: Oh now i understand. In java or c++ you can end the loop with `||`(if one is false, it ends), but here it is possible?

Comment: No, || (OR) would not return false after evaluating the first proposition. && (AND) would because logical conjunction requires both propositions to be true in order to produce true, so if the first one is false, it's settled, no need to go further. 

You should look the truth tables for logical conjunction (AND) and disjunction (OR) to understand why there is no need to evaluate the second proposition if the first proposition of a conjunction is false. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction

While loops and logical operators are pretty much the same in every language.